# Can this “amalgamation” of a sequence of real numbers be equal to an element of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $f(p,q) = 2^p \times (2q + 1) - 1$, where $p,q$ are natural numbers.

Let $G(x, b, i)$ denote the numeric value of an $i$-th element of the base-$(b+2)$ representation of the fractional part of a real number $x$, assuming that the first element has index $i=0$. For example, $$\begin{array}{l}
G(\pi, 0, 0) = 0,\\
G(\pi, 0, 1) = 0,\\
G(\pi, 0, 2) = 1,\\
G(\pi, 1, 3) = 2,\\
G(\pi, 3, 6) = 1,\\
G(\pi, 8, 4) = 9,\\
G(\pi, 10, 9) = 11,\\
G(\pi, 14, 3) = 15.
\end{array}$$

Let $S$ denote an infinite or finite [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) (an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed and order matters) of real numbers. Then $S_n$ denotes an $n$-th element of $S$.

Let $F(S)$ denote a real number such that $0 < F(S) < 1$ and an $f(f(n,b), f(i,x))$-th bit of the base-$2$ representation of the fractional part of $F(S)$ is $1$ if and only if $G(S_n, b, i) = x$. All other bits of the base-$2$ representation of the fractional part of $F(S)$ are $0$.

Question: does there exist a sequence $S$ such that $F(S)$ is equal to some element of $S$? If no (or yes), how to prove this?